# SnackBar and fitsSystemWindow

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-snackbar

I have an app that uses fitsSystemWindows to be able to draw an background behind Navigation- and Status-Bar - unfortunately the SnackBar seems to ignore the fitsSystemWindows=true from the container. I boiled the problem down to this minimal app:

[image: problem]

the style:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/accent_material_dark</item>
        <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">false</item>

        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button

            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

the activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                Snackbar.make(v,"This Snackbar should fitSystemWindows",Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Anyone knows some workaround?

I published the minimal app to show the problem here:
https://github.com/ligi/SnackBarFitsSystemWindowProblem

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Snackbar` will always look for a `CoordinatorLayout` to anchor itself in: when you don't have one, it uses the full content view (which in your case, includes the area under the status bar) - adding a `CoordinatorLayout` that has `fitsSystemWindows=true` should do it.﻿

Comment: Would this cascade down from Fragment? I have a fragment where I spawn this Snackbar though

Comment: @NeonWarge - You mean cascade up from a Fragment whose view is contained within a `CoordinatorLayout`? Yup.

Comment: yes, in fact, there is something messing it up. It doesn't respect that attribute for me :/ Its a ViewPager on an activity with 4 fragments.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the following line in place of any **CoordinatorLayout** in **Snackbar declaration** with **findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_navigation_view)** .

Answer (score -3):

Well The correct answer is add
`android:paddingbottom="50dp"` to your CoordinatorLayout
although i'm not sure if all navigation bar size's is 50 dp

Comment: navigation bar size is not always same, so if you want to go this way, you need to check [windowInsets](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsets.html)